# ¿Cuándo usar y es seguro emplear const_cast, static_cast, dynamic_cast, reinterpret_cast?

Tags: c++, casting

¿Cómo estar seguro o qué pautas seguir a la hora de usar los moldes explícitos  en `C++`?

Por lo que entiendo al usar los `moldes` le estamos pidiendo al compilador que pase de la comprobación de tipos, y eso no creo que sea muy bueno si uno no sabe exactamente qué molde usar. Por eso quería saber qué guías usan o cosas a tener en cuenta para decidirse por un tipo de molde u otro a la hora de modelar los datos, para determinadas situaciones, y así saber cuándo es seguro usar uno u otro.

1. `const_cast`
2. `static_cast`
3. `dynamic_cast`
4. `reinterpret_cast`

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**`static_cast`**

es la conversión utilizada por defecto. En este tipo de conversión se comprueba, en tiempo de compilación, que los tipos origen y destino son compatibles, de ahí lo de *static*. Quizás, las dos principales ventajas de este tipo de conversión son:

- La conversión es tan rápida como su homóloga de C
- La conversión únicamente es posible entre tipos compatibles

Al usar `static_cast` nos podemos encontrar con dos inconvenientes:

- Como no realiza chequeos de herencia, podemos acabar teniendo punteros no válidos.

  ```
  class A
  {
    // ...
  };

  class B : public A
  {
    // ...
  };

  class C : public A
  {
    // ...
  };

  A* ptr = new B;
  C* ptr2 = static_cast<C*>(ptr); // Compila pero no es correcto
  ```
- No funciona con herencias virtuales:

  ```
  class A
  { };

  class B : public virtual A
  { };

  A* ptrA = new B;
  B* ptrB = static_cast<B*>(ptrA); // Error en compilación
  ```

**`dynamic_cast`**

Esta conversión sirve precisamente para solucionar los problemas que hemos comentado de `static_cast`. Este tipo de conversión nos garantiza que la conversión se realiza sí y sólo sí el objeto es del tipo de destino. Para conseguir este resultado realiza una serie de chequeos internos, por lo que este tipo de conversión es sensiblemente más lenta que `static_cast`.

```
class A
{
  // ...
};

class B : public A
{
  // ...
};

class C : public A
{
  // ...
};

A* ptrA = new B;
C* ptrC = dynamic_cast<C*>(ptrA); // ptrC == nullptr
B* ptrB = dynamic_cast<B*>(ptrA); // ptrB == ptrA

C& refC = dynamic_cast<C&>(*ptrA); // excepción std::bad_cast
B& refB = dynamic_cast<B&>(*ptrA); // OK
```

Este tipo de conversión se utiliza básicamente cuando tenemos polimorfismo de por medio. No tiene sentido utilizarla en otros ámbitos. Hay que tener en cuenta que si tenemos herencia múltiple y se producen ambigüedades (se hereda dos veces de la misma clase) podemos tener problemas al utilizar este tipo de conversión.

También hay que tener en cuenta que `dynamic_cast` únicamente es capaz de comprobar la herencia "hacia abajo", luego no es capaz de realizar conversiones transversales:

```
class A
{
  // ...
};

class B
{
  // ...
};

class C : public A, public B
{
  // ...
};

A* ptrA = new C;
B* ptrB = dynamic_cast<B*>(ptrA); // Error de compilación, aunque C es también de tipo B
```

**`const_cast`**

Es una conversión que permite eliminar el modificador `const` de una referencia o un puntero. Esta conversión puede sernos de utilidad si necesitamos llamar a métodos `no-const` de un objeto que nos viene como `const`. El peligro que se esconde tras este tipo de conversiones es que no está permitido modificar objetos que se han creado como constantes, luego retirar su modificador `const` puede provocar resultados indeterminados en nuestra aplicación.

```
const std::string texto_const = "TEST";

texto_const.at(0) = 't'; // Error de compilación

std::string* ptr_no_const = const_cast<std::string*>(&texto_const);
ptr_no_const->at(0) = 't'; // resultado indeterminado
```

**`reinterpret_cast`**

Representa el último grupo de conversiones de este capítulo. Este tipo de conversión viene a significar "estoy a punto de hacer algo peligroso y tengo que ser consciente de ello". Este tipo de conversión admite, por ejemplo, conversiones entre punteros no compatibles entre sí. Entiéndase que este tipo de conversión hay que utilizarla con muchísimo cuidado ya que puede tener efectos devastadores sobre nuestro código.

Answer (score 7):

**`static_cast`** es lo primero que deberías intentar usar. Es capaz de realizar conversiones implícitas entre tipos (como `int` a`float`, o puntero a `void*`),  y también puede realizar llamadas a funciones explícitas de conversión (o implícitas). En muchos casos no es necesario especificar `static_cast` explícitamente, pero hay que tener en cuenta que la sintaxis `T(algo)` es equivalente a `(T)algo` y debería evitarse (más sobre esto después). `T(algo, algo_mas)` sin embargo es seguro, y siempre invoca al constructor.

`static_cast` también puede realizar conversiones a través de jerarquías de herencia. No es necesario al convertir hacia arriba (hacia una clase base), pero al convertir hacia abajo puede usarse siempre que no se esté realizando conversión a través de herencia `virtual`. Eso sí, no realiza comprobaciones, y el comportamiento de un `static_cast` hacia un tipo inferior en la jerarquía que no es en realidad el tipo del objeto no está definido.

---

**`const_cast`** se puede usar para añadir o quitar `const` a una variable; ningún otro conversor de C++ puede hacer eso (ni siquiera `reinterpret_cast`). Hay que tener en cuenta que la operación de modificar un valor que era `const` no está definida sólo si la variable original es `const`; sí es seguro usarlo para quitar el `const` de una referencia a algo que no estaba declarado con `const`. Esto puede ser útil al sobrecargar funciones miembro basadas en `const`, por ejemplo. También puede usarse para añadir `const` a un objecto, por ejemplo para invocar una sobrecarga de una función miembro.

`const_cast` funciona de forma similar en `volatile`, aunque no es tan común.

---

**`dynamic_cast`** se usa casi exclusivamente para gestionar polimorfismo. Puedes convertir un puntero o referencia de un tipo polimórfico a cualquier otro tipo de clase (un tipo polimórfico tiene al menos una función virtual, declarada o heredada). Puedes usarlo para más que simplemente convertir hacia abajo -- puedes convertir lateralmente o incluso hacia arriba en otra cadena. `dynamic_cast` buscará el objeto deseado y lo devolverá si es posible; si no lo es devolverá `NULL` para punteros, o lanzará `std::bad_cast` para referencias.

`dynamic_cast` tiene sin embargo algunas limitaciones. No funciona si hay múltiples objectos del mismo tipo en la jerarquía de herencia (lo que se conoce como 'herencia en diamante') y si no estás usando herencia `virtual`. Además sólo puede recorrer la herencia pública. No es capaz de recorrer la herencia `protected` ni la `private`. Esto no obstante es raramente un problema, ya que dichos tipos de herencia apenas se usan.

---

**`reinterpret_cast`** es la conversión más peligrosa. Convierte un tipo directamente en otro - como por ejemplo convertir un puntero en otro, o almacenar un puntero en un `int`, y todo tipo de cosas no recomendables. Principalmente, la única garantía que obtienes con `reinterpret_cast` es que sin conviertes de vuelta al tipo original, obtendrás exactamente el mismo valor (pero **no** en el caso de que el tipo intermedio sea más pequeño que el original). También hay unas cuantas conversiones que **`reinterpret_cast`** no puede hacer. Se usa principalmente para conversiones extrañas y manipulaciones de bit, como convertir un stream directamente en datos, o almacenar datos en los bits bajos de un puntero alineado.

***Fuente***: [When should static_cast, dynamic_cast, const_cast and reinterpret_cast be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/332086/4574)