# Violación de segmento C++ socket

Tags: c++, socket, punteros, debian

Estoy programando un servidor en C++, pero cuando recibo los datos del cliente me salta una violación de segmento, cuando recibo los datos:

```
    long long unsigned int* paquetes;//Creamos un puntero donde guardaremos el numero de paquetes que se reciben
    string nombre="";//Un string para recibir el nombre
    
    //Esperamos que se reciba datos desde el CLIENTE, en caso que se reciba 0 se producira un error, guardo lo recibido en BUFFER
    if(recv(this->CONEXION_CLIENTE,(void*)nombre.c_str(),1000,0)<0){cout<<"Se ha producido un error, se cierra la conexion"<<endl;close(this->CONEXION_SERVIDOR);}
    else{
        this->BUFFER=(string)nombre.c_str();//Guardamos el nombre en el Buffer
        cout<<"El mensaje reicbido es: "<<this->BUFFER<<endl;//Mostramos el nombre del archivo
        
        //Creamos el archivo
        Arch=new Archivo();
        Arch->Abrir((char *)(Ruta+this->BUFFER).c_str(),(char*)"wb");
        
        recv(this->CONEXION_CLIENTE,(void *)this->BUFFER.c_str(),100,0);//Recibimos el numero de paquetes que se necesitan
        paquetes=new long long unsigned int((long long unsigned int)stoul(this->BUFFER));//Guardamos el numero de paquetes
        
        for(long long unsigned int i=0;i<*paquetes;i++){

///////////////////// esta zona es donde me salta la violación de segmento

            memoria=new char[LONGITUD];//Reservamos un nuevo espacio en la memoria
            recv(this->CONEXION_CLIENTE,memoria,LONGITUD,0);//Recibimos el paquete
            Arch->Contenido(memoria);//Vertimos el contenido del mensaje sobre el fichero
            delete[] memoria;//Liberamos la memoria
//////////////////// hasta aquí
        }
        
        Arch->Cerrar();//Cerramos el archivo
        delete Arch;//Liberamos la memoria que usaba Arch
        delete paquetes;//Liberamos la memoria de paquetes
        bzero((char*)this->BUFFER.c_str(),sizeof(this->BUFFER));//Limpiamos el buffer
    }
```

Aquí adjunto el el código del método contenido:

```
inline void Archivo::Contenido(char* contenido){
    
    /*
    
        Añadimos contenido al archivo que habiamos creado
    
    */
    fputc(*contenido,this->ARCHIVO);
    cout<<++this->CONTADOR<<" Bytes"<<endl;
};
```

No entiendo por que salta la violación de segmento, cuando no accedo a ningún puntero no inicializado y cuando elimino un puntero tiene algún valor. Muchas gracias por su atención y un saludo.

Adjunto aquí un ejemplo mínimo verificable:

Código del main:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

#include "servidor.h"
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdio.h>

/*

    Comandos del servidor:
    ->RCV RUTA recibir un archivo y guardarlo en un determinado sitio


*/

#define PUERTO 9999

using namespace std;

void inicio(Servidor*);
inline string eliminar(string,int);

int main(int argc,char const *argv[]){
    
    Servidor servidor(PUERTO);//Creamos el servidor
    servidor.Iniciar_Servidor();//Iniciamos la conexión del servidor
    servidor.Aceptar();//Aceptamos la conexión
    inicio(&servidor);//Llamamos a la función servidor
    servidor.Cerrar();
    
    
    return 0;
}


void inicio(Servidor* S){
    /*
     
        Iniciamos el algoritmo de manejo del servidor por parte del cliente
    
    */
    
    string comando="";//Creamos una variable para almacenar los comandos que recibimos
    
    while(comando!="Desconectar"){//Entramos en bucle hasta que recibamos del cliente desconectar
        
        S->Recibir_Mensaje(&comando);//Recibimo un comando por parte del cliente
        
        if(comando[0]=='R' && comando[1]=='C' && comando[2]=='V'){//Se ha recibido el comando de recibir archivos (RCV)
            comando=eliminar(comando,4);
            S->Recibir(comando);//Pasamos la ruta donde se guardara el archivo dentro del servidor
        }       
        
    }
    S->Cerrar();//Cerramos la conexión con el servidor
    
}

inline string eliminar(string str1,int I){
    /*
     
        Creamos esta funcion eliminar caracteres no deseados
    
    */
    
    string str2="";
    
    for(int i=I;i<str1.length();i++)//Eliminamos los caracteres
        str2+=str1[i];  
    
    return str2;//Devolvemos una nueva cadena
}
```

Aquí añado el código de la cabecera Servidor.h:

```
#ifndef Servidor_h
#define Servidor_h

#include <iostream>

#include "archivo.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#ifndef LONGITUD
#define LONGITUD 1
#endif

#ifndef TAMANO_DE_PAQUETES
#define TAMANO_DE_PAQUETES 1024
#endif

using namespace std;


class Servidor{
    private:        
        int PUERTO, CONEXION_CLIENTE, CONEXION_SERVIDOR;//Creamos las variables donde guardaremos las conexiones
        socklen_t LONGC;//Guardamos la longitud de la estructura
        struct sockaddr_in SERVIDOR,CLIENTE;//Creamos la estructura correspondiente del SERVIDOR y el CLIENTE
        string BUFFER;//El BUFFER de los mensajes recibidos
        const string RUTA="cd /Servidor";//Creamos una constante para crear la carpeta del servidor
        
        Archivo* Arch;
        
    public:
        Servidor(){};
        Servidor(int);
        void Puerto(int*);
        void Iniciar_Servidor();
        void Aceptar();
        inline void Recibir(string);
        void Cerrar();
};


Servidor::Servidor(int PUERTO){
    
    /*
     
        Establecemos el socket del servidor, y el puerto al que se le corresponde
     
    */
    
    this->PUERTO=PUERTO;//Guardamos el puerto
    
    //Creamos el socket del SERVIDOR
    this->CONEXION_SERVIDOR=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    bzero((char*)&(this->SERVIDOR),sizeof(this->SERVIDOR));//Llenamos de bytes la estructura de SERVIDOR, con el numero indicado por el operador sizeof
    this->SERVIDOR.sin_family=AF_INET;
    this->SERVIDOR.sin_port=htons(this->PUERTO);//Convertimos el puerto a host
    this->SERVIDOR.sin_addr.s_addr=INADDR_ANY;//Con esta macro especificamos nuestra direccion  
    
};

void Servidor::Puerto(int* puerto){
    /*
    
        Guardamos el puerto donde conectamos
    
    */
    this->PUERTO=*puerto;
}

void Servidor::Iniciar_Servidor(){

    /*
    
        Iniciamos el servidor y lo ponemos a la escucha
    
    */
    
    system("cd /;mkdir Servidor");//Creamos la carpeta del servidor
    
    //Comprobamos si hay error al iniciar el SERVIDOR, y asignamos al puerto un socket
    if(bind(this->CONEXION_SERVIDOR,(struct sockaddr *)&(this->SERVIDOR),sizeof(this->SERVIDOR))<0){
        //Con el primer argumento le indicamos la conexion, con el segundo la estructura a comprobar, y el tercero pa logitud en bytes
        cout<<"Ha habido un error, se va a cerrar el SERVIDOR"<<endl;
        close(this->CONEXION_SERVIDOR);//Cerramos la conexion del SERVIDOR
    }
    
    listen(this->CONEXION_SERVIDOR,10);//Establecemos el SERVIDOR a la escucha de un máximo de 10 conexiones
    
}

void Servidor::Aceptar(){
    
    /*
    
        Aceptamos la conexion del cliente
    
    */
    
    LONGC=sizeof(this->CLIENTE);//Guardamos la longitud del CLIENTE
    CONEXION_CLIENTE=accept(this->CONEXION_SERVIDOR,(struct sockaddr *)&(this->CLIENTE),&(this->LONGC));//Aceptamos la conexion con el CLIENTE
    
    //Comprobamos si se ha conectado
    if((this->CONEXION_CLIENTE)<0){cout<<"No se ha podido conectar el CLIENTE"<<endl;close(this->CONEXION_SERVIDOR);}
    
    cout<<"conectado con: "<<inet_ntoa(this->CLIENTE.sin_addr)<<" "<<htons(this->CLIENTE.sin_port)<<endl;//Mostramos quien se esta conectando
}

inline void Servidor::Recibir(string Ruta){
    
    /*
     
        Recibimos un archivo del cliente
    
    */
    char* memoria;//Puntero donde almacenaremos el contenido del archivo
    long long unsigned int paquetes;//Creamos un puntero donde guardaremos el numero de paquetes que se reciben
    string nombre="";//Un string para recibir el nombre
    
    //Esperamos que se reciba datos desde el CLIENTE, en caso que se reciba 0 se producira un error, guardo lo recibido en BUFFER
    if(recv(this->CONEXION_CLIENTE,(void*)nombre.c_str(),1000,0)<0){cout<<"Se ha producido un error, se cierra la conexion"<<endl;close(this->CONEXION_SERVIDOR);}
    else{
        this->BUFFER=(string)nombre.c_str();//Guardamos el nombre en el Buffer
        cout<<"El mensaje reicbido es: "<<this->BUFFER<<endl;//Mostramos el nombre del archivo
        
        //Creamos el archivo
        Archivo Arch;
        Arch.Abrir((char *)(Ruta+this->BUFFER).c_str(),(char*)"wb");
        
        recv(this->CONEXION_CLIENTE,(void *)this->BUFFER.c_str(),100,0);//Recibimos el numero de paquetes que se necesitan
        paquetes=(long long unsigned int)stoul(this->BUFFER);//Guardamos el numero de paquetes
        
        memoria=new char[LONGITUD];//Reservamos un nuevo espacio en la memoria
        for(long long unsigned int i=0;i<paquetes;i++){
            
            recv(this->CONEXION_CLIENTE,memoria,LONGITUD,0);//Recibimos el paquete
            Arch.Contenido(memoria);//Vertimos el contenido del mensaje sobre el fichero
            
        }
        
        delete[] memoria;//Liberamos la memoria
        Arch.Cerrar();//Cerramos el archivo
        bzero((char*)this->BUFFER.c_str(),sizeof(this->BUFFER));//Limpiamos el buffer
    }
    
}

#endif
```

Y aquí adjunto el código de la cabecera Archivo.h:

```
#ifndef Archivo_h
#define Archivo_h

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>

#ifndef TAMANO_DE_PAQUETES
#define TAMANO_DE_PAQUETES 1024
#endif

using namespace std;

class Archivo{
    private:
        string NOMBRE;//Guardamo el nobre del archivo
        long long unsigned int LONGITUD_ARCHIVO;//Guardamos la longitud del nombre
        FILE *ARCHIVO;//Creamos el objeto archivo para manejar el archivo y recibir datos deol archivo
        long long unsigned int CONTADOR;//Lo usamos para contar los bytes que recibimos del cliente en un transmision de datos
        string LINEA;//Recogemos la linea del archivo que enviamos
        char* MODO;//El modo en elq ue se abre el archivo
    public:
        Archivo(){};
        Archivo(int longitud):LONGITUD_ARCHIVO(longitud){};
        void Abrir(char*,char*);
        inline void Contenido(const char*);
        void Cerrar();
};

void Archivo::Abrir(char* nombre,char* modo){
    
    /*
        Establecemos el nombre del archivo
    */  
    this->NOMBRE=nombre;//Guardamos el nombre del archivo
    this->MODO=modo;//Guardamos el modo del archivo
    this->ARCHIVO=fopen((this->NOMBRE).c_str(),this->MODO);//Abrimos el archivo
    
};

void Archivo::Cerrar(){
    /*
    
        Cerrar el archivo que habiamos creado
    
    */
    fclose(this->ARCHIVO);
};


inline void Archivo::Contenido(const char* contenido){
    
    /*
    
        Añadimos contenido al archivo que habiamos creado
    
    */
    fputc(*contenido,this->ARCHIVO);
    cout<<++this->CONTADOR<<" Bytes"<<endl;
};

#endif
```

Aquí he aplicado los cambios de eliminar el puntero de `Arch` y el de `paquetes`.

Aquí adjunto el código, del cliente que uso para enviar el archivo:

```
import socket
import time as t
import math as m
import os
import sys
import chardet as c

class enviar():
    def __init__(self):
        #Creamos la conexión
        self.emisor=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)

        ip='localhost'
        puerto=9999
        #Conectamos
        self.emisor.connect((ip,int(puerto)))

        #Enviamos archivo
        nombre_archivo='Archivo.zip'
        archivo=open(nombre_archivo, "rb")
        ruta="RCV /Servidor/Sub_carpeta1/"
        self.emisor.send(ruta.encode('UTF-8'))
        t.sleep(1)
        self.emisor.send(nombre_archivo.encode("UTF-8"))
        t.sleep(1)
        self.emisor.send(str(os.path.getsize(nombre_archivo)).encode('UTF-8'))
        t.sleep(1)

        for i in archivo:
            self.emisor.send(i)
        archivo.close()

        self.emisor.send("Desconectar".encode("UTF-8"))

        self.emisor.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    enviar()
```

Comment: Es difícil darte una respuesta completa sin saber los tipos y sin un [mcve], pero haces cosas **muy mucho** mal hechas: usas un `std::string` como *buffer* de lectura sin reservar espacio, *casteas* de `const char *` a `std::string`, haces `new int` de **1 solo elemento** pero luego lo tratas como si fuera un *array* ... Vamos, que la respuesta es casi reescribir tu código por completo :-/

Comment: A modo de consejo inicial, evita usar punteros si no es necesario. En tu caso, no hay ninguna ventaja en que `paquetes` sea un puntero... y lo mismo con `Arch`

Comment: De la misma manera, dado que `LONGITUD` es una constante, no deberías recrear el puntero `memoria` en cada iteración, sino que podrías crearlo antes de empezar el `for` y destruirlo una única vez al finalizar el mismo

Comment: @eferion he aplicado el cambio que me has dicho, y he quitado el puntero de ```paquetes``` y el de ```Arch```, pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo, al terminar me da una violación de segmento. También he inicializado ```memoria``` antes del for y después de este he liberado el espacio, pero la violación de segmento se sigue dando.

Comment: @Trauma, siento que te parezca que hay muchas cosas mal hechas, soy nuevo en C++ y aprendo de manera autónoma, agregaré ahora un ejemplo mínimos verificable.

Comment: @pablogac A ver, entiendo tu caso. Pero deberias probar *pasito a pasito* y no meterte *hasta el fondo* de golpe. Intenta crear una variable `std::string` y hacer un `strcpy( )` a ella, tal y como lo haces. Eso ya es una pregunta. Y así con lo que te indico. Te quedarán mas claros los conceptos.

Answer (score 2):

**El peligro de los punteros**

```
Arch->Abrir((char *)(Ruta+this->BUFFER).c_str(),(char*)"wb");
```

La función `c_str` te devuelve un `char const*` o puntero a char constante, por una razón, y es que esta función te expone, directamente, la memoria interna del `std::string` encargada de almacenar la cadena de texto.

Esto significa que ese puntero no te pertenece a tí sino al objeto de tipo `std::string`. Esto significa que si se modifica el objeto `std::string`, el valor al que apuntas puede variar o incluso dejar de ser válido (por ejemplo si se hace un realloc porque se necesite más espacio). Adicionalmente también significa que si el objeto `std::string` deja de existir, esa región de memoria dejará de ser válida.

Pues bien, si despiezamos tu aplicación en instrucciones individuales tenemos lo siguiente:

```
{
  std::string temp = Ruta + this->BUFFER;
  Arch->Abrir(temp.c_str(), "wb");
}
```

Las llaves no son casuales, el objeto `temp` solo va a existir hasta que se realice la llamada a `Arch->Abrir`, pasado ese punto, el objeto será destruído y ello conlleva que la región de memoria apuntada por `temp.c_str()` dejará de ser válida y cualquier intento de usar dicho puntero tendrá efectos indeterminados.

Usas los punteros con demasiada alegría, es algo que deberías evitar. A modo de ejemplo, una implementación similar pero mucho más segura:

```
//                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Ahora los parámetros son de tipo std::string
bool Archivo::Abrir(std::string const& nombre, std::string const& modo)
// ^ devolvemos un bool, será true si se ha podido abrir el archivo
{
    this->NOMBRE = nombre;//Guardamos el nombre del archivo
    this->MODO = modo;//Guardamos el modo del archivo
    this->ARCHIVO=fopen(this->NOMBRE.c_str(),this->MODO);//Abrimos el archivo

    return (this->ARCHIVO != nullptr); // Lo mismo el archivo no ha podido abrirse 
} // Las funciones no terminan con punto y coma
```

Con lo que ahora la llamada podría quedar así

```
if( !Arch->Abrir(Ruta+this->BUFFER, "wb") )
{
  // Mostrar mensaje de error
  // abortar la ejecución
  // ...
}
```

Como ves, queda más legible, más bonito y además es más seguro.

Destaca el hecho de que no verifiques que el archivo se ha podido abrir ... esta es la posibilidad más probable de cara a tu fallo. Tu código no lo puede probar porque no puedo lanzar el servidor (en esta máquina no tengo python) ... solo el cliente.

**Conversiones en C++**

Las conversiones heredadas de C son, por definición, peligrosas y una prueba de ello la tienes en el código que ha dado pie al punto anterior:

```
(char *)(Ruta+this->BUFFER).c_str()
```

C++ dispone de su propio catálogo de conversiones, las cuales son mucho más seguras y fáciles de localizar. Puedes obtener más información al respecto visitando la siguiente [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/6/463)

**Uso de referencias**

En otro orden de cosas, en C++ intenta usar las referencias en vez de los punteros cuando sea posible. Esto es, siempre que la función no vaya a ser la responsable del objeto.

Así, por ejemplo, la función `inicio`, bien podría estar escrita así:

```
void inicio(Servidor & S){
    /*
     
        Iniciamos el algoritmo de manejo del servidor por parte del cliente
    
    */
    
    string comando="";//Creamos una variable para almacenar los comandos que recibimos
    
    while(comando!="Desconectar"){//Entramos en bucle hasta que recibamos del cliente desconectar
        
        S.Recibir_Mensaje(&comando);//Recibimo un comando por parte del cliente
        
        if(comando[0]=='R' && comando[1]=='C' && comando[2]=='V'){//Se ha recibido el comando de recibir archivos (RCV)
            comando=eliminar(comando,4);
            S.Recibir(comando);//Pasamos la ruta donde se guardara el archivo dentro del servidor
        }       
        
    }
    S.Cerrar();//Cerramos la conexión con el servidor
    
}
```

A nadie se le ocurre, por ejemplo, hacer un `delete` sobre una referencia, lo que evita que en algún momento puedas tener un *doble delete*.

De la misma manera, los parámetros que no vayan a ser modificados dentro de la función deberían estar etiquetados como `const`.

**Objetos de C**

```
FILE *ARCHIVO;
```

Si programas en C++ intenta, en la medida de lo posible, hacer uso de clases y funciones específicas de C++. Si bien C++ incorpora mucha funcionalidad de C, ésta existe sobretodo por cuestiones de compatibilidad con código antiguo, no siendo recomendable su uso en código moderno.

Los motivos son varios:

- Las funciones de C no están pensadas para trabajar con tipado fuerte, muchas de ellas admiten punteros a `void*`, lo cual es un peligro en potencia
- Las funciones de C no admiten los objetos de C++. No puedes, por ejemplo, pasarle un `std::string` a `printf` directamente... tienes que hacer *apaños*.
- Los objetos de C son meras estructuras en las que todo es público, no permiten aprovechar el principio de encapsulación y toda la responsabilidad recae en el programador
- ...

C++ dispone de varias clases para la manipulación de archivos:

- `std::ifstream` para leer archivos
- `std::ofstream` para escribr archivos
- `std::fstream` para leer y escribir archivos

Con estas clases **no hace falta usar punteros**, puedes usar los objetos por valor, lo que limita los posibles errores en el código.

**Uso de mayúsculas**

A la hora de trabajar con ordenadores, por favor, limita al máximo el uso de mayúsculas. Debido a que las pantallas de ordenador son discretas (la unidad mínima de información es el pixel), su resolución es limitada y las tipografías en mayúsculas acaban cansando demasiado la vista (se leen peor). Por si esto no fuese suficiente motivo, la cultura popular usa las mayúsculas para representar gritos, luego al escribir las variables en mayúsculas parece que estuvieses gritando...

no vas a encontrar ninguna norma de codificación que aliente el uso desmesurado de mayúsculas a la hora de programar... por favor, no lo hagas tu.

**EDICIÓN**

> Pero la violación de segmento sigue apareciendo, además ha aparecido otro error, cuando recibe el nombre del archivo lo recibe con caracteres binarios chat.zip�>�+

Este error lo estabas teniendo antes, pero no eras consciente de ello.

El primer problema que tienes aquí es que estás escribiendo directamente en la memoria del `std::string`... y no sabes cuánta capacidad ha reservado ese objeto, pero seguramente sean menos de 1000 caracteres, luego es probable que acabes pisando memoria:

```
std::string nombre;
nombre.reserve(1000); // Garantizamos espacio para 1000 caracteres (incluyendo el nulo final)
```

Aunque para este tipo de usos, es decir, llamar a funciones de C porque no hay más remedio, recomendaría usar arrays de tamaño fijo

```
char nombre[1000];
```

Por otro lado, para solucionar el error que sí que ves, tienes dos opciones:

1. reseteas el buffer del socket antes de leer:

   ```
    bzero(nombre,sizeof(nombre));
   ```
2. lees la cantidad de bytes que has recibido y pones el bit correspondiente a 0

   ```
    int bytes = recv(this->CONEXION_CLIENTE,nombre,1000,0);
    if( bytes < 0 )
    {
      cout<<"Se ha producido un error, se cierra la conexion" << endl;
      close(this->CONEXION_SERVIDOR);
    }
    else
    {
      nombre[bytes] = '\0'; // Finalizamos la cadena
      // ...
    }
   ```

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicación del ```c_str()``` y del motivo por el cuál no se debe usar la conversión de C. He aplicado los cambios que me has dicho, y he usado la función que me propones para Abrir el archivo, Además he añadido a los argumentos que no van a ser modificados el ```const```. También he tratado de sustituir los argumentos de punteros por referencias. Pero la violación de segmento sigue apareciendo, además ha aparecido otro error, cuando recibe el nombre del archivo lo recibe con caracteres binarios ```chat.zip�>�+```. Sigo en el siguiente comentario.

Comment: Supongo que tendría que limpiar de alguna manera la entrada del socket antes de recibir el siguiente mensaje. Además el uso de las funciones de C para tratar con archivos se debe a que las de C++ me daban error al tratar de escribir el archivo que estaba recibiendo. Siento lo del uso de las mayúsculas, pero el motivo por el que lo había hecho para poder diferenciar a simple vista las variables de privadas de la clase del resto de variables.

Comment: @efeiron acabo de leer los últimos cambios que me has propuesto, y ya me funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias por la ayuda y un saludo.