# A que se refiere esto *(float *)v en C++?

Tags: c++, punteros

Estoy de forma autodidacta aprendiendo C++, tengo este codigo y tengo una duda:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
   char cadena[10] = "Hola";
   char *c;
   int *n;
   void *v;

   c = cadena; // c apunta a cadena
   n = (int *)cadena; // n también apunta a cadena
   v = (void *)cadena; // v también
   cout << "carácter: " << *c << endl;
   cout << "entero:   " << *n << endl;
   cout << "float:    " << *(float *)v << endl;
   return 0;
}
```

Por lo que llevo aprendiendo, entiendo que al comienzo de estas lineas dentro de la funcion main(){} estamos declarando una cadena, y 3 punteros. Donde el puntero v no tiene un dato especificado y es por eso que tiene void delante. Entonces se le asigan las variables a los punteros. Sin embargo, no comprendo que quiere decir (int *) y (void *) delante de los punteros "n" y "v". Tampoco entiendo a que se refiere en el ultimo cout esto: *(float *)v.

Comence este lenguaje hace como 4 dias, hasta ahora todo perfecto con variables, bucles, estructuras, tipos de datos, arrays, funciones y etc... Sin embargo, esto de los punteros es nuevo para mi, ya que yo vengo de Python3, Dart y JavaScript, pero nunca vi esto sobre punteros, si pueden explicarme eso se les agradece.

Answer (score 4):

Son dos operaciones que se ejecutan de forma consecutiva.

Lo primero que tenemos es una conversión, `(float *)`. Con esto cogemos `v`, que es un puntero a `void`, y forzamos a que le compilador lo trate como si fuese un puntero a `float`.

La segunda operación es el asterisco `*`. Lo que hace es obtener el valor al que apunta `v`, pero tratándolo como si fuese un `float` (por eso se ha hecho la conversión anterior).

Si dividimos el código en etapas más sencillas tendríamos lo siguiente:

```
float* punteroFloat = (float*)v;
float valor = *punteroFloat;
cout << "float: " << valor;
```

La idea detrás de estas operaciones es leer lo que haya en la memoria apuntada por `v` como si fuese un dato de tipo `float`. Tu podrías alegar que ahí no hay números sino letras, concretamente la palabra `"hola"`, pero para el ordenador eso no son más que bits, concretamente (y haciendo uso de una tabla ASCII), `v` apunta a lo siguiente:

```
 h    o    l    a    \0
0x68 0x6F 0x6C 0x61 0x00
```

Entonces, lo que hace el programa es leer el dato `0x686F6C61` como si fuese un entero y como si fuese un `float`.

Bueno, aquí hay que hacer una aclaración, y es que aquí podemos encontrar dos posibles soluciones en función de si nuestra máquina es *big endian* o *little endian*, pero eso es material para otra respuesta.

Ahora bien, tratándose de C++, sería más seguro y legible usar las conversiones propias de C++, en este caso `static_cast`:

```
float * punteroFloat = static_cast<float*>(v);
```

Dejándolo todo en una sola línea, como sucedía con tu ejemplo, quedaría así:

```
cout << "float:    " << *static_cast<float *>(v) << endl;
```

Para más información acerca de las conversiones propias de C++ puedes consultar [esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/6/463)

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad, ahora sí entendí, explicaste muy bien.