# Existe el casteo implícito en C++

Tags: c#, c++, c++98

Tengo un programa en el que tengo dos clases:

```
class Clase_Base{};

class Clase_Der: public Clase_Base{};
```

Me gustaría saber si se puede hacer algo como el casteo implícito en C# que se declara dentro de la clase de forma tal que una instancia de Clase_Base sea también (si es posible) un objeto de tipo Clase_Der sin que sea necesario hacer un casteo explícito en la instancia

Answer (score 0):

Un objeto de tipo `ClaseBase` no puede en ningún caso ser de tipo `ClaseDer`.

En cambio, un objeto de tipo `ClaseDer` sí que puede comportarse como uno de tipo `ClaseBase`:

```
Clase_Basebase;
Clase_Derder;

Clase_Base* ptrBase1 = &base; // OK
Clase_Base* ptrBase2 = &der;  // OK

Clase_Der* ptrDerivada1 = &base; // ERROR
Clase_Der* ptrDerivada2 = &der;  // OK
```

El hecho de que tengas un puntero de tipo `Clase_Base` no implica que esté apuntando a objetos de dicho tipo, como ves también es capaz de apuntar a objetos de tipos derivados. Sin embargo, un puntero de un tipo derivado no será capaz de apuntar a un objeto de tipo base.

Por otro lado, existen las funciones virtuales. Estas funciones permiten que un objeto de tipo `Clase_Der` casteado a `Clase_Base` siga teniendo sus funciones disponibles:

```
class Clase_Base
{
public:
    void func_no_virtual() const { std::cout << "BASE\n"; }

    virtual void func_virtual() const { std::cout << "BASE\n"; }
};

class Clase_Der : public Clase_Base
{
public:
    void func_no_virtual() const { std::cout << "DER\n"; }

    void func_virtual() const { std::cout << "DER\n"; }
};

Clase_Base base;
base.func_no_virtual();  // BASE
base.func_virtual();     // BASE

Clase_Derivada der;
der.func_no_virtual();   // DER
der.func_virtual();      // DER

Clase_Base * ptr = &base;
ptr->func_no_virtual();  // BASE
ptr->func_virtual();     // BASE

ptr = &der;
ptr->func_no_virtual();  // BASE
ptr->func_virtual();     // DER  <<--- Funcion virtual
```

Usar un puntero de clase base para direccionar objetos de clases derivadas es lo que se conoce como polimorfismo.

Para recuperar un objeto derivado a partir de un puntero de clase base debemos recurrir al uso de `dynamic_cast`:

```
class Clase_Base
{ };

class Clase_Der1 : public Clase_Base
{ };

class Clase_Der2 : public Clase_Base
{ };

Clase_Der1 der1;
Clase_Der2 der2;

std::cout << "Caso 1\n";

Clase_Base * ptr = &der1;

if (dynamic_cast<Clase_Der1*>(ptr) != NULL) // Conversion valida
{ std::cout << "ptr apunta a objeto de tipo Clase_Der1\n"; }

if (dynamic_cast<Clase_Der2*>(ptr) != NULL) // Esta conversion devolvera NULL
{ std::cout << "ptr apunta a objeto de tipo Clase_Der2\n"; }

std::cout << "Caso 2\n";

ptr = &der2;

if (dynamic_cast<Clase_Der1*>(ptr) != NULL) // Esta conversion devolvera NULL
{ std::cout << "ptr apunta a objeto de tipo Clase_Der1\n"; }

if (dynamic_cast<Clase_Der2*>(ptr) != NULL) // Conversion valida
{ std::cout << "ptr apunta a objeto de tipo Clase_Der2\n"; }
```

También es posible usar `static_cast`, pero en este caso debemos estar seguros de que el objeto es del tipo esperado (o de un tipo derivado). Si no es así el programa empezará a comportarse de forma extraña:

```
 Clase_Der1 der;

 Clase_Base * ptrBase = &der;

 Clase_Der1 * ptrDer = static_cast<Clase_Der1*>(ptrBase); // OK

 Clase_Der2 * ptrDer = static_cast<Clase_Der2*>(ptrBase); // Compila, comportamientos indefinidos
```

Para más información acerca de las conversiones propias de C++ puedes consultar esa otra pregunta: [¿Cuándo usar y es seguro emplear const_cast, static_cast, dynamic_cast, reinterpret_cast?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/6/cu%c3%a1ndo-usar-y-es-seguro-emplear-const-cast-static-cast-dynamic-cast-reinterp/)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, la verdad necesito usar métodos definidos en Clase_Base que devuelven tipo Clase_Base dentro de Clase_Der y que devuelvan tipo Clase_Der. No es necesario cambiar el método, solo el tipo de retorno para no tener que castear a Clase_Der cada vez que ejecute el método.